# Convert folders with opus

Tags: directory, flac, ogg-opus

I have this command to convert all .flac files from a directory to .opus

```
for flacfile in *.flac ;do opusenc --bitrate 64 "$flacfile" "${flacfile%.flac}.opus" ;done
```

What command should I use to do the same thing but including sub-folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `**/*.flac`:

```
for flacfile in *.flac **/*.flac; do opusenc --bitrate 64 "$flacfile" "${flacfile%.flac}.opus"; done
```

Comment: it worked perfectly. thank you!